# Qt 5.6 + multimedia + gstreamer

Tags: qt, ubuntu, gstreamer, multimedia, qt5.6

Okay here's the deal. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, have installed Qt 5.6, qtmultimedia5-dev, gstreamer0.10 (and 1.0), and libqtgstreamer-dev.

I am STILL getting this error when I try to use a QAudioDecoder:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.audiodecode"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late. I'm having the same problem. Installing gstreamer plugins solved the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem on Kubuntu 16.04 and QT 5.7. I've installed all the above and still get "no service found" for the org.qt-project.qt.camera

Comment: I'm now running 16.04 and most audio codecs from gstreamer, including MP3s don't work. I think it has something to do with gstreamer relying on ffmpeg, whereas Ubuntu has moved to libav