# Which Gstreamer in PyQt5?

Tags: python, ubuntu, qt5, pyqt5, gstreamer

On Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 whenever I'm trying to use `QMediaPlayer` I'm being prompted with no service.

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia
>>> qtm = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

The Internet suggests installing some Gstreamer packages but it doesn't say which. How can I figure out which package is needed?

It seems that by default Ubuntu comes with `Gstreamer1.0` and I can run `gst-play-1.0 FILEPATH`. Any chance that `gstreamer-0.10` is needed instaed? How can I set reverse the dependency?

Packages which I have installed

```
notlaptop@laptop$ apt list --installed | grep gstream*    
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-alsa/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0/bionic,now 3.0.26-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-gl/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-packagekit/bionic,now 1.1.9-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-qt5/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-tools/bionic,now 1.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-x/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-gl1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-opencv1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-dev/bionic,now 1.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer/bionic,now 1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt 5.6 + multimedia + gstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465073/qt-5-6-multimedia-gstreamer)

Comment: Honestly no idea why negative points. I understand this question has been asked many times but nothing I found is working. I have installed all plugins before and it wasn't working. Had to delete them.

Comment: install `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev ` package

Comment: you have to install the packages but with termination `-dev`, those are for developers.

Comment: Forgot how toxic StackOverflow can be. I'm guessing people think this is more Ubuntu related question than programming. Will move question.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc for your help. Unfortunately none helped.

Comment: I think there are more packages missing, but look for the ones that have -dev at the end of the name, those are the ones that are used to develop since they are the ones that provide the .so and the .h, your question as you indicate is more appropriate for ubuntu since it refers to installation of packages.

Comment: for example: `gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dev`

Comment: I cannot find any `gstreamer-*-dev` in my repo and so there isn't `gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dev`. Only `-dev` start with `libgstreamer`.

Comment: install: `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev` and `libgstreamer1.0-dev`

Comment: Both are `is already the newest version (1.14.0-1)`

Comment: see this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html#multimedia-dependencies,

Comment: and install `libqt5gstreamer-dev `

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc for trying to help. I've already went through all of these a while back; installed everything I could find with `gstreamer`. This is just not helpful. Thought that Ubuntu is rather popular distribution and someone might have figured it out but all I'm getting are open tickets everywhere and toxic approach. Will pause for a bit and in the worst case try something else than `Qt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by installing almost everything I could find which was remotely connected with `gstream` and `qtmultimedia`. I'm not sure which are necessary but the current list is below.

For testing it's good to clean cached python executable so that it doesn't use older version. This is not only in the same dir but also `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`.

The cherry on this package cake was `libqt5multimedia5-plugins`.

Installed list for **gstream**

```
$ apt list --installed | grep gstream
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer-qapt/bionic,now 3.0.4-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer0.10-qapt/bionic,bionic,now 3.0.4-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
gstreamer1.0-alsa/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0/bionic,now 3.0.26-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-espeak/bionic,now 0.4.0-3 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3/bionic,now 0.10.32.debian-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-gl/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-libav/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-nice/bionic,now 0.1.14-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-packagekit/bionic,now 1.1.9-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-qt5/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-tools/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-vaapi/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-x/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-gl1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-opencv1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-0/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-dev/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamerd-3-0/bionic,now 3.7.5-2build1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamerd-3-dev/bionic,now 3.7.5-2build1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamermm-1.0-1/bionic,now 1.10.0+dfsg-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamermm-1.0-dev/bionic,now 1.10.0+dfsg-1 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamer-dev/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamerquick-1.0-0/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamerui-1.0-0/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamerutils-1.0-0/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer/bionic,now 1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
qml-module-qtgstreamer/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
```

and fot **qt5**

```
$ apt list --installed | grep qt5
gstreamer1.0-qt5/bionic-updates,now 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libdbusmenu-qt5-2/bionic,now 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libphonon4qt5-4/bionic,now 4:4.10.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpolkit-qt5-1-1/bionic,now 0.112.0-5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5concurrent5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5core5a/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5dbus5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5designer5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5glib-2.0-0/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamer-dev/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamerquick-1.0-0/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamerui-1.0-0/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gstreamerutils-1.0-0/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5gui5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libqt5help5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5multimedia5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5multimedia5-plugins/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libqt5multimediawidgets5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5network5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5opengl5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5opengl5-dev/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5printsupport5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5qml5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5quick5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5script5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5sql5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5sql5-sqlite/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5svg5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5test5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5texttospeech5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5waylandclient5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5waylandcompositor5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5widgets5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5x11extras5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5xml5/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
phonon4qt5/bionic,now 4:4.10.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
phonon4qt5-backend-vlc/bionic,now 0.10.1-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pyqt5-dev/bionic,bionic,now 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 all [installed]
pyqt5-examples/bionic,bionic,now 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 all [installed]
python-pyqt5/bionic,now 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
python-pyqt5.qtmultimedia/bionic,now 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5/bionic,now 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5-dbg/bionic,now 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia/bionic,now 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia-dbg/bionic,now 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
qt5-gtk-platformtheme/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qt5-qmake/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qt5-qmake-bin/bionic,now 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5/bionic,now 1.2.0-5 amd64 [installed]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Qt5.10 you can downgrade to 5.8 or replace the files in plugins/mediaservice/ with older versions. That works for me.